# Pandas Group By With Running Total

Tags: pandas

My granny has some strange ideas. Every birthday she takes me shopping.
She has some strict rules. If I buy a present less than $20 she wont contribute anything. If I spend over $20 she will contribute up to $30.

So if a present costs $27 she would contribute $7.

That now leaves me with $23 to spend on extra presents that birthday; the same rules as above apply on any additional presents.

Once the $30 are spent there are no more contributions from granny and I must pay the rest myself.

Here is an example table of my 11th, 12th and 13th birthday.

```
                         DollarsSpent  granny_pays
BirthDayAge PresentNum                           
11          1                  25.00         5.00   -- I used up $5
            2                 100.00        25.00   -- I used up last $20
            3                  10.00         0.00
            4                  50.00         0.00
12          1                  39.00        19.00  -- I used up $19 only $11 left
            2                   7.00         0.00
            3                  32.00        11.00  -- I used up the last $11 despite $12 of $32 above the $20 starting point
            4                  19.00         0.00
13          1                  21.00         1.00  -- used up $1
            2                  27.00         7.00  -- used up $7, total used up $8 and never spent last $22
```

So in pandas I have gotten this far.

```
import pandas as pd
granny_wont_pay_first = 20.
granny_limit = 30.

df = pd.DataFrame({'BirthDayAge' : ['11','11','11','11','12','12','12','12','13','13']
                   ,'PresentNum' : [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2]
                   ,'DollarsSpent' : [25.,100.,10.,50.,39.,7.,32.,19.,21.,27.]
              })

df.set_index(['BirthDayAge','PresentNum'],inplace=True)
df['granny_pays'] = df['DollarsSpent'] - granny_wont_pay_first
df['granny_limit'] = granny_limit
df['zero'] = 0.0
df['granny_pays'] =  df[['granny_pays','zero','granny_limit']].apply(np.median,axis=1)
df.drop(['granny_limit','zero'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print df.head(len(df))
```

And this is the output. Using the median on the 3 numbers is a nice way to work out what granny will contribute.

The problem is that you can see each present is treated in isolation and I don't  correctly erode my $30 each present within each BirthDayAge.

```
                      DollarsSpent  granny_pays
BirthDayAge PresentNum                           
11          1                  25.00         5.00
            2                 100.00        30.00 -- should be 25.0
            3                  10.00         0.00
            4                  50.00        30.00 -- should be 0.0
12          1                  39.00        19.00
            2                   7.00         0.00
            3                  32.00        12.00 -- should be 11.0
            4                  19.00         0.00
13          1                  21.00         1.00
            2                  27.00         7.00
```

Trying to think of a nice pandas way to do this erosion.

Hopefully no loops please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more concise way, but this should work and does avoid loops as requested.

```
df['per_gift'] = df.DollarsSpent - 20
df['per_gift'] = np.where( df.per_gift > 0, df.per_gift, 0 )

df['per_bday'] = df.groupby('BirthDayAge').per_gift.cumsum()
df['per_bday'] = np.where( df.per_bday > 30, 30, df.per_bday )

df['granny_pays'] = df.groupby('BirthDayAge').per_bday.diff()
df['granny_pays'] = df.granny_pays.fillna(df.per_bday)
```

Note that 'per_gift' ignores the maximum subsidy of $30 and 'per_bday' is the cumulative subsidy (capped at $30) per 'BirthDayAge'.

```
  BirthDayAge  DollarsSpent  PresentNum  per_gift  per_bday  granny_pays
0          11            25           1         5         5            5
1          11           100           2        80        30           25
2          11            10           3         0        30            0
3          11            50           4        30        30            0
4          12            39           1        19        19           19
5          12             7           2         0        19            0
6          12            32           3        12        30           11
7          12            19           4         0        30            0
8          13            21           1         1         1            1
9          13            27           2         7         8            7
```

Comment: alas I'm long past school.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358754/pandas-apply-transform-error-invalid-dtype-determination-in-get-concat-dt