# Pandas Apply(), Transform() ERROR = invalid dtype determination in get_concat_dtype

Tags: pandas

Flowing on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334068/pandas-group-by-with-running-total), which i link as background, but question is standalone.

**4 questions:**

1. I cannot understand the error I see when using apply or transform:
   **"invalid dtype determination in get_concat_dtype"**
2. Why does ClipNetMean work but the other 2 methods not?
3. Unsure **if or why** i need the **.copy(deep=True)**
4. Why the slightly different syntax needed to call the InnerFoo function

The DataFrame:

```
              cost
section item      
11      1       25
        2      100
        3       77
        4       10
12      5       50
        1       39
        2        7
        3       32
13      4       19
        1       21
        2       27
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'section' : [11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13]
                   ,'item' : [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2]
                   ,'cost' : [25.,100.,77.,10.,50.,39.,7.,32.,19.,21.,27.]
              })
df.set_index(['section','item'],inplace=True)

upper =50
lower = 10

def ClipAndNetMean(cost,upper,lower):
    avg = cost.mean()
    new_cost = (cost- avg).clip(lower,upper)
    return new_cost

def MiniMean(cost,upper,lower):
    cost_clone = cost.copy(deep=True)
    cost_clone['A'] = lower
    cost_clone['B'] = upper
    v  = cost_clone.apply(np.mean,axis=1)
    return v.to_frame()

def InnerFoo(lower,upper):
    def inner(group):
        group_clone = group.copy(deep=True)
        group_clone['lwr'] = lower
        group_clone['upr'] = upper
        v  = group_clone.apply(np.mean,axis=1)
        return v.to_frame()
    return inner

#These 2 work fine.
print df.groupby(level = 'section').apply(ClipAndNetMean,lower,upper)
print df.groupby(level = 'section').transform(ClipAndNetMean,lower,upper)

#apply works but not transform
print df.groupby(level = 'section').apply(MiniMean,lower,upper)
print df.groupby(level = 'section').transform(MiniMean,lower,upper)

#apply works but not transform    
print df.groupby(level = 'section').apply(InnerFoo(lower,upper))
print df.groupby(level = 'section').transform(InnerFoo(lower,upper))

exit()
```

So to Chris's answer, note that if I add back the column header the methods will work in a Transform call.

see **v.columns = ['cost']**

```
def MiniMean(cost,upper,lower):
    cost_clone = cost.copy(deep=True)
    cost_clone['A'] = lower
    cost_clone['B'] = upper
    v  = cost_clone.apply(np.mean,axis=1)
    v = v.to_frame()
    v.columns = ['cost']
    return v

def InnerFoo(lower,upper):
    def inner(group):
        group_clone = group.copy(deep=True)
        group_clone['lwr'] = lower
        group_clone['upr'] = upper
        v  = group_clone.apply(np.mean,axis=1)
        v = v.to_frame()
        v.columns = ['cost']
        return v
    return inner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 & 2)  `transform` expects something "like-indexed", while `apply` is flexible.  The two failing functions are adding additional columns.

3) In some cases, (e.g. if you're passing a whole `DataFrame` into a function) it can be necessary to copy to avoid mutating the original.  It should not be necessary here.

4) The first two functions take a `DataFrame` with two parameters and returns data.  `InnerFoo` actually returns another function, so it needs to be called before being passed into `apply`.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Interesting so for TRANSFORM  "like-indexed" means on BOTH axis. I was thinking that my .apply(np.mean,axis=1) would be sufficient, the row axis=0 stayed the same and the call collapsed me back to a single column. BUT I loose the header on the column index axis =1. So i note that if I rename the column back to the original I'm good. I'll add in the example.